# Why is the default max length for an input 524288?

Tags: html, w3c, html-input

The default maximum length for a HTML input (`<input type="text">`) is `524288` characters.  That seems like a very peculiar number, why was it chosen?

Comment: It is documented, at least [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Did I miss something? That just documents that it is set to `524288`, not *why* it's set to that, which is what the OP is asking...

Comment: @BenM: Yes, it was a comment to someone else asking how OP found that number.

Comment: Is it limited by the spec, or is that just a limitation imposed by certain browsers?  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44883

Comment: I don't think it's limited by the spec. Chrome devs found a performance problem with text longer than that and so they clamped the maxLength and apparently they forgot about it after that

Comment: w3c doesn't seem to mention it http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes only that it needs to be a positive number and should reflect the intended contents of the input element. Are you this is true across browsers? w3schools is hardly a reliable source.

Comment: I think that they wanted a value that is not too long to avoid security problems, but enough to store information. Maybe they decided to use a power of 2 and they chosen to be 2^19 just because in hex it looks nice: 80000.

Comment: 524288 bytes is 512 kilo bytes

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate that was the first thing I tried as a conversion using Google converter, but it came out at 524.288Kilobytes.  Looks like Google have adopted the new standard and it's actually 512Kibibytes, hence my initial confusion :)

Comment: The question claims that there is a default length, presumably meaning a *maximum* length, without citing any reference. Even if there were such a default, it would be non-constructive and hence off-topic at SO to speculate *why* it exists.

Comment: @Korpela, even if the sources are not official, the post seems to be ok. That number is specified on http://www.w3schools.com/ and it also can be obtained by typing `document.getElementById("myText").maxLength` in Chrome console. It can be edited, but it is on-topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) the maximum value is unlimited:

> maxlength = number [CN]
>
> When the type attribute has the value "text" or "password", this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters the user may enter. This number may exceed the specified size, in which case the user agent should offer a scrolling mechanism. **The default value for this attribute is an unlimited number.**

Despite that, I have noticed that in Chrome indeed defaults the `maxlength` to 524288, which seems a 'bug 'to me, or at least a deliberate choice to cap the input to 512KB (thanks to [Benjamin Udink ten Cate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859762/benjamin-udink-ten-cate) for pointing that out).

Comment: Ah, so it is 512KB.  I assumed it was a totally random number, because it's not actually 512_kilo_bytes, but 512_kibi_bytes.  Google converter must use the latest standard

Comment: I was initially confused because 524288 bytes isn't 512KB any longer (it was recently changed to base 1000), which is what prompted my original question.  All sorted now though, thanks

Comment: @mikemike: Thanks. I didn't get your comment "because 524288 bytes isn't 512KB any longer" though. Can you explain?

Comment: Sure.  The standard changed recently.  524288 bytes is now 524.288KB - https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=524288%20bytes%20in%20kilobytes - what we're used to being a kilobyte is now a 'kibibyte': https://www.google.co.uk/webhp#q=524288+bytes+in+kibibyte

Comment: @mikemike: That's just marketing. I will keep it to code ;) . It has been this for years, and in my opinion it still is.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale, other than to confuse 99.9% of people who know what a [x]byte is (or was).  Very annoying!  That's what prompted the question initially anyhow, as I just did a quick Google conversion, expecting the number to be 512KB, but instead got a random number

Comment: "The standard changed recently." This seems like an entirely meaningless statement. The number of bits involved in the representation should be all that matters for coding purposes.

Comment: @codetaku : Yes, no one is disagreeing.  Google's converter is reporting a different number of 'KB', as it uses the kibibyte standard instead of the kilobyte we're all used to, which is where my confusion came from.  A kibibyte is 1024 bytes, a kilobyte is 1000 as it was recently changed (I find it highly irregular that a unit of measure can just be changed, but apparently it can) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte

Comment: Interesting thing I noticed, looks like Chrome has changed the default max length to -1. It looks like this change occurred recently (within a year or few I'd guess). If you look at some of the web tests in the Chromium GitHub mirror (https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?p=1&q=maxLength&unscoped_q=maxLength) you'll see that it's now testing that the default value is -1. This makes sense since that must be their equivalent of unlimited.