# Javascript maxLength on tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have found on the internet that the maxlenght for an input is :

524288 characters

I can't find any information regarding textArea.

I need to passe a var that can be up to 1 500 000 characters, so I try to find something similar to an input text or a textArea or label that can be use for that.

So my question is, is there a tag capable of such a huge capacity (If you can tell me the max lenght capacity of tag element it could be nice too) ?

Comment: Where "on the internet" did you get that information? I don't believe it's correct. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @Pointy http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: I think you got confused or misread it. [It is the default value](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Comment: I'd try `<div contentEditable='true'>...</div>` for this as an editable area receiving that amount of data.

Comment: That reference (which is questionable anyway) simply says that the **default** is 524288. That's not correct (the W3C spec calls the default `maxlength` "unlimited"), but it certainly doesn't imply that the default is also the absolute maximum.

Comment: @Pointy [looks like it's in the spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469152/why-is-the-default-max-length-for-an-input-524288), but that appears to be default, not max digit possible.

Comment: @zvona I know about the content editable, but I need something that can be understand by a C# update panel, so a basic tag will be more usefull for my case.

Comment: @SterlingArcher [I don't think so.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-maxlength)

Comment: If you'd describe what it is you're actually trying to do, you might get more useful answers. Or you could just try an `<input>` tag and see what happens.

Comment: @Pointy already try with an input, I just wanted to know the maximum capacity of différents type of tag to choose the most efficient one for my purpose.

Comment: What does "efficient" mean? What are you measuring to determine efficiency?

Comment: @Pointy the time taken the set my big variable to the component choosen. The fact that the default value of a maxlength is there means I have to set it myself so it take all my variable

Comment: If you don't set `maxlength` at all then there is no limit other than when one process or another runs out of memory. Again, nobody knows what exactly it is that you're trying to do, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: And, again, that w3schools page you found is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

textarea has a [maxlength attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)

```
<textarea maxlength="number">
```

[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html) doesn't put any limit on the limit of this value

but there is a [max limit to the integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) itself

So, you can put `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` characters in the textarea, which is around

```
 Math.pow(2, 53) - 1     // 9007199254740991
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: This is no use for the question, I know how to set a max lenght, I seek to find the limite of this number

Comment: @Slayner there is no limit as per the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.integer.non-negative

Comment: @Slayner it depends on the your browser and system's ram as well. I don't think there are any limits as such

Answer (score 1):

You probably understood it. The link clearly said that it is the **default value**. There is no upper limit to the maxlength. You can store unlimited characters using the maxlength.

Comment: @Slayner:- As answered and said, it is the default value which is present in your link. But if you see the w3c spec then you will see that there is no such value defined.

Comment: Hmmm unlimited seems odd, regarding the impact on performance.

Comment: @Slayner:- `regarding the impact on performance` Not sure which performance issue you are thinking of?

Comment: I'm thinking about the time taken to passe the variable to the input field with a "inputFiled.innerHTML= variable".

Comment: @Slayner:- Did you try to  check and find any performance issue with that? I am not sure if you will get any! :)

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) he is correct. It's unlimited if *maxLength* is not specified. The limiting factor at this point is the GET/POST request size look limit imposed on your setup.