# Text box character limit

Tags: html, materialize

I created a simple textbox with MaterializeCSS. It had a character counter similar to what can be found here - http://materializecss.com/forms.html

While playing with it, I found out that the textbox had a limit of 524288 characters. You can try for yourself with the Character Counter example in the given link.

My question is: Why is that so? Shouldn't the maxlength be set to unlimited by default? Or did it have something to do with using MaterializeCSS?

Comment: For me such a high value is unlimited as I don't know a reason to type in so many chars into a text box. Good to know anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit is not imposed by MaterializeCSS, it looks like a limitation used by some browsers.

I tested the following snippet on Chrome Developer Tools (48.0.2564.116) and the output is 524288:

```
document.getElementById("first_name").maxLength = 9999999;
document.getElementById("first_name").maxLength;
```

There is a question related here ([Why is the default max length for an input 524288?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469152/why-is-the-default-max-length-for-an-input-524288)).