# sonar plugin failed to read surefire reports

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-4.5

I am doing a SonarQube analysis, and it looks the sonar-maven-plugin is having trouble reading the xml being created by surefire report.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project abc: Fail to parse the Surefire report: /apps/home/builder/name/work/cmpub/trunk/abc-plugins/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.abc.platform.services.publisher.transformer.OMtoMinSubmissionConverterTest.xml: Maximum attribute size limit (524288) exceeded -> [Help 1]

Here is maven and java details:
Maven home: /apps/maven/maven-3.3.1
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Has anyone ever faced this, please suggest.

Comment: Could you have a look to the content of the Surefire report because looks like you're facing a more generic issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469152/why-is-the-default-max-length-for-an-input-524288