# How to bind 'maxlength' attribute?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I can render the following Angular 2 component containing an `<input>` with a `maxlength` set:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<input maxlength="10">',
})
export class App {
}
```

This works fine. However, if I try to set the `maxlength` via a binding, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<input [maxlength]="maxLength">',
})
export class App {
    maxLength = 10;
}
```

Or like this:

```
  template: '<input maxlength="{{maxLength}}">',
```

I get the following error:

```
"Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'maxlength' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."
```

Why? `maxlength` is a perfectly valid property of an `<input>` element.

Here's a [live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxb10urctYezQUuPGyTj?p=preview) (open console to see error).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

excerpts from [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings),

**Attribute Binding**

> We become painfully aware of this fact when we try to write something
> like this:
>
> ```
> <tr><td colspan="{{1 + 1}}">Three-Four</td></tr> We get this
> ```
>
> error:
>
> ```
> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'colspan' since it
> isn't a known native property
> ```
>
> As the message says, the  element does not have a colspan property. It has the "colspan" attribute, but
> interpolation and property binding can set only properties, not
> attributes.
>
> We need attribute bindings to create and bind to such attributes.
>
> Attribute binding syntax resembles property binding. Instead of an
> element property between brackets, we start with the prefix attr,
> followed by a dot (.) and the name of the attribute. We then set the
> attribute value, using an expression that resolves to a string.

Here's a relevant Stack Overflow post about [the difference between properties and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html).

You may try below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<input [attr.maxlength]="maxLength" >',
})
export class App {
    maxLength = '10';
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the updated and it works [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/CkAbaQLQVndoC47OtQRF?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks so much. What does that mean, how did it occur to you, is there documentation about it, etc.?  I just need to know how to explain this to my coworkers.

Comment: Good answer - supported by the Angular docs which recommend this exact approach (which is required to support the Angular MaxLengthValidator) - https://angular.io/api/forms/MaxLengthValidator

Answer (score 0):

we upload  [attr.maxlength]="[field?.maxCharacters || '9999']"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would suggest the initial value of input type="text" meaning: [attr.maxlength]="[field?.maxCharacters || '524288']"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469152/why-is-the-default-max-length-for-an-input-524288